# How to store a large number of records in android mobile memory?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write an android app which store the data offline . 
For example , consider the below record.

```
 Name   |  address |  contact_number |    city   |      remarks 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AAAAA  |    CCC   |      123456     |  New Yark |  StackOverFlow member
```

I need to store 10000 records as like above in that mobile database. 
Is this possible? . Please suggest technology and ideas to achieve this requirement.
Also the app size should not exceed 15 MB.

What is the difference in case if I maintain in flat file and use SQLLite?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
You can choose between a **CSV** text file (after all, it's only a table - and text files are higly compressable) or a SQLite **db**

Answer (score 1):

Your application can include SQLite Data Base directly on the APK package. When running the first time, copy the database to the internal memory of the device, and from that moment you use it as a normal database.